# Get set of numbers from string without regex

Tags: c#, string, substring

> ```
> "abc_d1.txt" should get 0
> "abc_d1_2.txt" should get 2
> "abc_d1_14.txt" should get 14
> "abc_d12_x2_156.txt" should get 156
> ```

Can do this currently with regex

```
 int Id;
 string pattern = @"(?<=_)\d+(?=\.\w+)|(?<!_\d+)(?=\.\w+)";
 Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
 var z = rg.Match(fullFileName).Value;
 Id = z == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(z);
```

But how to do it without regex?

Comment: You could iterate the string, and once you find a `_` check if the next character is a digit. If yes, read on until the next non-digit.

Comment: If you have a regex way, what's the rationale behind avoiding it? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use regex (I don't judge). However, assuming everything is exactly as you have described, and you need no validation. A low tech approach would be to just `Split` the string, `TryParse` the results, then call `LastOrDefault`

**Given**

```
private static int GetNumber(string input)
  => input.Split('_','.')
      .Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out var value) ? value : (int?)null)
      .LastOrDefault(x => x != null) ?? 0;
```

**Usage**

```
var asd = new List<string>()
{
   "abc_d1.txt",
   "abc_d1_2.txt",
   "abc_d1_14.txt",
   "abc_d12_x2_156.txt"
};

foreach (var result in asd.Select(GetNumber))
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
0
2
14
156
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic string manipulation:

```
int u = s.LastIndexOf('_');
return  int.TryParse(s.Substring(u + 1, s.Length - u - 5), out int i) ? i : 0;
```

(Following on from the comment) - the 5 is a bit of "magic number" I guess - it's the length of the extension ".txt" 4 plus 1 to negate the effect of u being one index short (because it's pointing to the position of the underscore, not the position of the first char of the number after it). I could have written `s.Substring(u + 1, s.Length - (u + 1) - 4` but this form might self-explain a little better:

```
int begin = s.LastIndexOf('_') + 1;
return  int.TryParse(s.Substring(begin, s.Length - begin - 4), out int i) ? i : 0;
```

Comment: `s.Length - u - 5` the `- 5` comes from the length of `.txt` + 1, right?

Comment: The LastIndexOf gives the index of the underscore, but you want the character after. I suppose I could have said `int u = s.LastIndexOf('_') + 1` and then the calc would have been `s.Substring(u, s.Length - u - 4)` or even `s.Substring(u, s.Length - u - ".txt".Length)` :)

Comment: I would rather have think about using `int d = s.LastIndexOf('.');` and `s.Substring(u + 1, d - u - 1)`, to make sure it takes any extension length. And happy new year !

Comment: Yep, that works too.. I was just imagining that you had a billion of these things, and being able to easily avoid another search operation on the string to find the `.` (when its position is fixed/can be calculated) could be an improvement. I'd say go for whatever balance of readbility and performance you need. This method is certainly an improvement over parsing the string with regex or going to the effort/cpu/memory of splitting it into an array of strings, most of which will be thrown away